# Parameters of Filters

Tags: ros, arm-navigation, trajectory-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone!!!

Anyone know where could I find the parameter list of the filterChain from filter's package?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28396/parameters-of-filters/) by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2012-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `laser_filters` documentation can be found [here](http://ros.org/wiki/laser_filters). The parameters for each node are listed there.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on 2012-02-26**:
Thanks for you answer Dimitri, but my problem with filters package is when i use the arm_navigation stack.
The velocity and acceleration are not consistent with the desired time. For example: If I required the trajectory with a final time of 30 minutes or 10 second, the result trajectory take less 3 seconds for completion.
Any ideas?